# Win2012 - Background Application Whitespace CORRUPTION?

Tags: background, corruption

This is a really odd one:  Could I ask any experienced Windows developers to please look at these screencaps,  and advise if they've ever seen anything like this before:  *corrupted background whitespace,  in Windows 2012*:   see these mages - these are seen within Win2012 VMs running on HyperV on  Win2012 host:

[screencap 1 - showing whitepace corruption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBlsh.jpg)

[screencap 2 - another view of whitespace corruption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfOaj.jpg)

I should say - the machine *works perfectly still*:  this is purely a visual effect, and appears to be a corruption of some sort of background (font??)  - every new application pane opened, shows it - Windows Explorer does - but as soon as appn writes to the whitespace,  it clears the corruption away.

This is an RDP view to the server but that seems unrelated: the actual RDP desktop background is not affected,  just the whitespace in each Windows application pane.  That's why I wonder if it's something to do with a font corruption or related.

Hoping to resolve it without a complete rebuild: is part of an industrial server application on a client site.

All wisdom will be gratefully received.

Thanks very much

Mike, London

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd say this is a question for superuser.com (another StackExchange site) and is offtopic here, since it does not include any actual coding issue, but rather an issue with usage of third-party software. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks YakovL.    I don't agree that this is off-topic:   I've come to StackExchange with this as this is where I find  solutions to many technical issues working in IT.    There are a very large number of experienced computer users here who seem to have met every kind of application circumstance,  and this is an operational problem with Windows which may well have been seen before by someone else.  It's not specifically a 'superuser' issue - any experienced IT person (like myself) may have met and resolved an issue like this.  So I'd like to see what comments arise in coming days - thanks.

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but SO's rules state that one shouldn't ask questions "not directly related to *writing* computer programs" (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) even though a lot of experienced guys are here. At http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you may find some more hints. On the contrast, the on-topic section of SU looks like that's exactly where you should ask: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic